# android SeekBar - remove on focus lost

Tags: android, focus, seekbar

I am creating a simple app that displays a gridview with a menu at the top. One of the menu buttons when clicked places a seekbar on the view right below it.  The user can then move the slider to change the size of the items in the gridview.  I can handle that part just fine, the issue comes when trying to get rid of the seekbar.  I need a way to find out when the seekbar has lost focus.  I tried using the setOnFocusChangeListener but it never seems to get called.  Some of the code is below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    SeekBar seek;

    public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getId() == R.id.menu_grid_size)
        {
            if(seek != null) {
                seek = new SeekBar(this);
                seek.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
                ...
                layout.addView(seek, layoutparams);
            } else {
                layout.removeView(seek);
                seek = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onFocusChange(Viewv, boolean hasFocus) {
        layout.removeView(seek);
    }

}
```

Everything works except when I scroll through the list the seekbar is still visible.  Maybe this isnt the best way to do what I want, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I modified the code above to fix an error I was getting when you click the button twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think found a solution that I think works pretty well.  Since I am using the seekbar I use the onStopTrackingTouch() method to find out when the use lifts their finger and use that as an indicator of when to remove the slider.

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    if(seekBar != null){
        layout.removeView(seekBar);
        seekBar = null;
}
```